# GridBagLayout Alignment Issue with Button expanding Column Width

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create an interface with some JLabels icons ( box icons )and an exit button. The thing is that, when I place the button under the labels, they split, according to the button's position like this:

[image: example]

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL; // Adding space before the labels
c.gridy = 0;
c.weighty = 1;
add(new JLabel(" "), c);

for(int i = 0; i < label.length; i++){  // Adding the JLabels       
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridx++;
    add(label[i], c);
}
// Adding the button
c.gridy ++;
c.gridx = 2;    // Changing the value of gridx, will move the button to that location and it will split another jlabel.
c.weighty = 0.09;
add(eButton, c);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: why don't you nest the `GridBagLayout` in a panel which is placed into the center of a `borderLayout` and then add the exit button in another panel using `flowLayout` which can then be placed south of the `borderLayout`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: Place the button at gridx 0, set the gridwidth to REMAINDER and the anchor to CENTRE

Comment: agreed with @MadProgrammer's comment, and if you want to add space before/after/above/below anything, just modify the insets instead.

Comment: Thank you guys. @MadProgrammer Why can't i just use anchor NORTH or CENTER on the jlabels ?

Comment: I simply don't get this GridBagLayout...

Comment: Get some grid paper, that's `GridBagLayout`, each component resides within a cell. You can specify that a component can "expand" columns and rows

Answer (score 0):

`GridBagLayout` works a lot like a grid paper, it has rows and columns, components are placed within those cells; you can specify how additional space is distributed and components are aligned within those cells.

Each row and column is sized based on the layout requirements of the other components in that row/column, this means that a component may have more space than it needs, because some other component in the same row/column needs more space to be laid out.

You can also allow a component to span across multiple rows/columns, allowing to occupy more space.

So, basically, what you need to do is tell the button that it can occupy all the columns for it's row (or at least the 5 columns which is occupied by the labels).  You will need to then tell the button that it needs to be aligned to the center of it's area.

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL; // Adding space before the labels
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.weighty = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  // Adding the JLabels       
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                c.weighty = 0;
                c.gridy = 1;
                c.gridx++;
                c.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
                JLabel label = new JLabel() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(20, 20);
                    }
                };
                label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
                add(label, c);
            }
            c.gridy++;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
//          c.weighty = 0.09;
            add(new JButton("Exit"), c);
        }

    }

}
```

Take a closer look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details